# what is the devise_mapping variable and how can I include it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I'm trying to implement authentication with Devise in my Rails application (Rails 2.3.8, Devise 1.0.7, mongrel running on Windows Vista). But I'm getting the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `devise_mapping' for #<ActionView::Base:0x6d63890>
```

This is when I use the auto-generated partial _devise_links.html.

```
<%- if controller_name != 'sessions' %>
  <%= link_to t('devise.sessions.link'), new_session_path(resource_name) %><br />
<% end -%>

<%- if devise_mapping.registerable? && controller_name != 'registrations' %>
  <%= link_to t('devise.registrations.link'), new_registration_path(resource_name) %><br />
<% end -%>

<%- if devise_mapping.recoverable? && controller_name != 'passwords' %>
  <%= link_to t('devise.passwords.link'), new_password_path(resource_name) %><br />
<% end -%>

<%- if devise_mapping.confirmable? && controller_name != 'confirmations' %>
  <%= link_to t('devise.confirmations.link'), new_confirmation_path(resource_name) %><br />
<% end -%>

<%- if devise_mapping.lockable? && controller_name != 'unlocks' %>
  <%= link_to t('devise.unlocks.link'), new_unlock_path(resource_name) %><br />
<% end -%>
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? I'm assuming the devise_mapping variable is not getting included in my views, but what do I do about it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I realize this question is kind of old, but I think I figured out why you can't just render that partial. The partial you're trying to render is the partial for the links that show up below the sign_in/sign_up form.

If you'd like to add those links to your application, [this page on the Devise Wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-sign_in,-sign_out,-and-sign_up-links-to-your-layout-template) will show you how to do it, and it involves creating your own partial(s).

**EDIT (2019-04-01):** Copying the information from the Devise wiki page here for persistence.

> #### How To: Add sign_in, sign_out, and sign_up links to your layout template
>
> First add sign_in/out links, so the appropriate one will show up depending on whether the user is _already_ signed in:
>
> ```
> # views/devise/menu/_login_items.html.erb
> <% if user_signed_in? %>
>   <li>
>   <%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete) %>        
>   </li>
> <% else %>
>   <li>
>   <%= link_to('Login', new_user_session_path)  %>  
>   </li>
> <% end %>
> ```
>
> The `method: :delete` part is required if you use the default HTTP method.  To change it, you will need to tell Devise this:
>
> ```rb
> # config/initializers/devise.rb
>   # The default HTTP method used to sign out a resource. Default is :delete.
>   config.sign_out_via = :get
> ```
>
> You can then omit `method: :delete` on all your sign_out links.
>
> Next come the sign_up links.  Again, these can be substituted with something else useful if the user is already signed in:
>
> ```
> # views/devise/menu/_registration_items.html.erb
> <% if user_signed_in? %>
>   <li>
>   <%= link_to('Edit registration', edit_user_registration_path) %>
>   </li>
> <% else %>
>   <li>
>   <%= link_to('Register', new_user_registration_path)  %>
>   </li>
> <% end %>
> ```
>
> Then use these templates in your `layouts/application.html.erb`, like this:
>
> ```
> # layouts/application.html.erb
> <ul class="hmenu">
>   <%= render 'devise/menu/registration_items' %>
>   <%= render 'devise/menu/login_items' %>
> </ul>
> <%= yield %>
> ```
>
> Add some menu styling to the CSS (here for a horizontal menu):
>
> ```css
> ul.hmenu {
>   list-style: none; 
>   margin: 0 0 2em;
>   padding: 0;
> }
>
> ul.hmenu li {
>   display: inline;  
> }
> ```

Answer (score 45):

You can add helper methods to `ApplicationHelper`. Make sure to use the proper model name (in my case it's `:user` representing the `User` model).

```
def devise_mapping
  Devise.mappings[:user]
end

def resource_name
  devise_mapping.name
end

def resource_class
  devise_mapping.to
end
```

**Update 1/28/2014**

The master branch of Devise shows that `devise_mapping` is now stored in the request:

```
# Attempt to find the mapped route for devise based on request path
def devise_mapping
  @devise_mapping ||= request.env["devise.mapping"]
end
```

And `resource_name` is aliased as `scope_name` as well. See [devise_controller.rb](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise_controller.rb#L36) for more info.

Comment: No me funciono el Update.  Me quedo con el anterior.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `devise_mapping`, you can use `Devise.mappings[:user]`, given that the user class in question is User.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have the devise_for call in your routes.rb file?

For instance, if you are using it for your User class, then the route would be:

devise_for :users

for more info, see https://github.com/plataformatec/devise